Не выполняется сохранение данных формы в БД
Не могу определить, в чем конкретно  проблема.
Есть форма:
<form class="form-cr" action="{% url 'events:create_event' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="cont-a">
                    <div class="name name">
                        <label for="id_title">Название*</label>
                        <input class="inner-input" type="text" name="title" id="id_title" placeholder="Введите название" required autocomplete="off" value="{% if form.title.value %}{{ form.title.value}}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="url name">
                        <label for="id_slug">Url-адрес*</label>
                        <input class="inner-input" type="text" id="id_slug" name="slug" placeholder="Заполняется автоматически" value="{% if form.slug.value %}{{ form.slug.value}}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-file-row">
                        <div>Изображение*</div>
                        <label class="input-file" for="image-input">
                            <div class="input-caption">Вставьте изображение</div>
                            <input class="inner-input-file" type="file" name="poster" id="image-input" value="{% if form.poster.url %}{{ form.poster.url }}{% endif %}" accept="image/*">
                        </label>
                        <div class="upload-preview" id="upload-preview-div">
                            <img class="upload-preview-img" src="{{ form.poster.url }}" alt="" id="image-preview" style="display: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description name">
                        <label for="id_description">Описание</label>
                        <input class="inner-input" type="text" name="description" id="id_description" placeholder="Краткое описание" value="{% if form.description.value %}{{ form.description.value}}{% endif %}">
                    </div>
                    <button class="enter__btn" type="submit">Создать</button>
                </div>
                <div class="cont-b">
                    <div class="age name">
                        <label for="id_age">Возраст</label>
                        <select class="select-age" name="age" id="id_age">
                            {% if form.age.value %}
                            <option value="">{{ form.age.value }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            <option value="">Выберите значение</option>
                            <option value="6+">6+</option>
                            <option value="12+">16+</option>
                            <option value="18+">18+</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="genre name">
                        <label for="id_genre">Жанр</label>
                        <select class="select-genre" id="id_genre" name="genre">
                            {% if form.genre.value %}
                            <option value="">{{ form.genre.value }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            <option value="">Выберите значение</option>
                            <option value="Классика">Классика</option>
                            <option value="Драма">Драма</option>
                            <option value="Комедия">Комедия</option>
                            <option value="Детектив">Детектив</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-day name">
                        <label for="id_day">Когда*</label>
                        <input class="time-inp" type="number" name="day" id="id_day" placeholder="день" required value="{% if form.day.value %}{{ form.day.value}}{% endif %}">
                        <input class="time-inp" type="text" name="month" placeholder="месяц" required value="{% if form.month.value %}{{ form.month.value}}{% endif %}" id="id_month">
                        <input class="time-inp" type="text" name="hours" placeholder="время чч:мм" required value="{% if form.hours.value %}{{ form.hours.value}}{% endif %}" id="id_hours">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

Представление:
def edit_event(request, slug, day, month, hours):

    if not request.user.has_perm('events.change_events'):
        raise PermissionDenied
        
    event = Events.objects.get(slug=slug, day=day, month=month, hours=hours)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=event)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('events:home')
    else:
        form = EventForm(instance=event)
    context = {
        'title': 'Event - Edit',
        'form': form,
        'event': event
        }
    return render(request, 'events/edit_event.html', context)

При нажатии на "Создать" выполняется ф-я "create_event", но данные в базу данных не передаются, и не выполняется редирект, следующий после "form.save()"
Консоль выдает просто: "POST /events/create-event/ HTTP/1.1" 200 56891

Все дело оказалось в forms.py:
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField()
    slug = forms.SlugField()
    poster = forms.FileField()
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
    age = forms.CharField(required=False)
    genre = forms.CharField(required=False)
    day = forms.IntegerField()
    month = forms.CharField()
    hours = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = (
            'title',
            'slug',
            'poster',
            'description',
            'age',
            'genre',
            'day',
            'month',
            'hours'
        )

ModelForm по умолчанию делает все поля обязательными, даже если в модели указано blank=True и null=True, а чтобы поля были необязательными, надо явно это указать: required=False
